# Uncaught Error: Class "GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise"

Tags: php, cron, backend, guzzle

I tried implementing the below code but it is showing the `EachPromise Error class not found` and `Promise Error class not found`. Guzzle library is installed. Then also this error was there.

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;

$users = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

$promises = (function () use ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        
        // Using generator
        yield $this->getAsync(
'https://api.demo.com/v1/users?username='
        . $user);       
    }
})();

$eachPromise = new EachPromise($promises, [
    
    // Number of concurrency
    'concurrency' => 4,
    'fulfilled' => function (Response $response) {
        if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            $user = json_decode(
                $response->getBody(), true);
            
            // processing response of the user
        }
    },
    
    'rejected' => function ($reason) {
    // handle promise rejected
    }
]);
$eachPromise->promise()->wait();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seem there is no autoloader that locates and loads the class files mentioned in your code.

If your Guzzle package is installed with composer, you may try `require_once()` the `/vendor/autoloader.php` file in your source root.

Otherwise, try loading those class files individually - which is not recommended in modern PHP world(use autoloader whenever possible).

```
require_once("path-to/EachPromise.php");
require_once("path-to/Response.php");
```

---

**EDIT**

In the second sight, your code uses `$this` that requires an object instance context with `$this->getAsync()` being available, but apparently not so. The code seems like a partially copy-pasted code fragment from a Class object that won't run in your given set up.

You may need to set up the code context of your sample code.

Comment: After adding the require_once files , facing this error 
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function EachPromise()
For this code
```$eachPromise = new EachPromise($promises, [
 
 // Number of concurrency
 'concurrency' => 4,
 'fulfilled' => function (Response $response) {
  if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
   $user = json_decode(
    $response->getBody(), true);
   
   // processing response of the user
  }
 },
 
 'rejected' => function ($reason) {
 // handle promise rejected
 }
]);```

Comment: is there any way to implement this particular code